# Network problems after Ubuntu upgrade

Tags: ubuntu, networking, networkmanager

I'm having real problems having upgraded Ubuntu from 10.04 to 10.10. My main problem is I cannot get a network connection either wired or wireless. When I right click the Network manager applet the Enable Networking check box is greyed out and unchecked.

Any ideas how to resolve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Network Manager may ignore interfaces configured in /etc/network/interfaces, so check that your interface isn't already in there. If it is, remove it and reboot.

Network Manager has a config file for which interfaces to manage at /etc/NetworkManager/nm-system-settings.conf  It may have `managed=false` which you could need to change to true.

The network manager service may not be running. `ps -ef | grep NetworkManager`  If it's not running `sudo service network-manager start`